# Filter all packages that not use a specific port

Tags: wireshark

I use wireshark to watch a captured pcap file. I see a lot of communication on a specific port, that I am not interessted in, so i want to filter it to see only the rest of the communication.

I used this filter rule: `tcp.dstport != 1337 and tcp.srcport != 1337` to remove all tcp communication on port 1337. But as it seems this rule also removes all non TCP traffic. For example DNS requests are not shown anymore.
If i change the filter to `(tcp.dstport != 1337 and tcp.srcport != 1337) or ! tcp` it shows all traffic except port 1337/tcp but it does not seems to be the "correct" way to do it. Is using `tcp.dstport` or `tcp.srcport` equal to filter only tcp traffic and then filtering the port?

Answer (score 2):

Your filter should be:

```
!(tcp.port == 1337)
```

**Explanation**

There are 2 kind of filters in *Wireshark*:

1. **Capture filter**: used when capturing traffic (duh?) and built with the Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF) syntax (check manpage of [pcap-filter](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html)). *libpcap* is the underlying library doing the actual capture.
2. **Display filter**: used to reduce the amount of traffic you see and built with a [proprietary syntax](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html) (some of it overlapping with the BPF one).

Your display filter `tcp.dstport != 1337` should be read as *"the packet contains a field named tcp.port with a value different from 1337"*. As a result, packets **without** a `tcp.port` field will be filtered out.